# How to hide random div on btn click via JS method .hide

Tags: javascript, random, hide

Here's the issue:

1. Got multiple divs which can get hidden (random 90 items gets hidden out of total 100) on btn click via method .style.visibility = 'hidden'
2. However this means all hidden divs will leave a blank space in between of the rest of visible divs
3. Need to fix this by applying the .hide method instead of .style.visibility one to the code
4. Too bad is I Can't figure out how to get .hide be working just fine

Here's what I got:

HTML

```
<html>
<body>

<button id="hide-containers" onclick="hide()">Hide random containers</button>

<div class="container">Item 1</div>
<div class="container">Item 2</div>
...
<div class="container">Item 99</div>
<div class="container">Item 100</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS .style.visibility method /// working pretty fine but leaving blank spaces in between of divs

```
    function hide() {
    var cubes = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
    for (var i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++) {
        cubes[i].style.visibility = '';
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 90;) {
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        if (cubes[y].style.visibility == '') {
            cubes[y].style.visibility = 'hidden';
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

JS .hide method // not working tho

```
    function hide() {
    var cubes = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
    for (var i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++) {
        cubes[i].style.visibility = '';
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 90;) {
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        for (var cubes){.hide(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Question:
How to rework the JS code to run it succesfully via the method .hide and so prevent hidden divs leaving a blank space in between of remaining visible divs?

Thank you guys for giving me a hand with this.

Comment: Use `.style.display = 'none'` to hide, `.style.display = 'block'` to show.

Comment: I think you are referring to jQuery' [`.hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) method.

Comment: Thanks! .style.display worked just awesome.. and yeah its jQuery method sry im new in this. Just one more question: how to prevent .style.display = 'none' to continually hide all divs on repetual clicking the button? I need that to hide the same amout of 90 divs out of 100 on each click? Now it's targeting just the actual and remaining amount of shown divs I think... so after few clicks all divs are hidden. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to the hint with .style.display = 'none' and style.display = 'block' I have found the correct code composition. Posting result, this is working solution for my question:

JS

```
function hide() {
    var cubes = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
    for (var i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++) {
        cubes[i].style.display = '';
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 90;) {
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        if (cubes[y].style.display == '') {
            cubes[y].style.display = 'none';
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Use css `display` for the spacing problem, or move the element out of the page, using a css class. The following snippet does the latter. It uses [event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and no jQuery. Furthermore, if you want to hide 90 containers (so keep 10 containers in sight), you'll need *unique* random numbers. So, the snippet contains a factory method for that. The snippet first hides all containers, then displays 10 random of them.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", hide);

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", `<div class="container">Item ${i+1}</div>`);
}

function uniqueRandomFactory(max) {
  let randomCache = [];

  const uniqueRandom = () => {
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    if (!randomCache.find(el => el === r)) {
      randomCache.push(r);
      return r;
    }
    return uniqueRandom();
  };

  return uniqueRandom;
}

function hide(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === "hide-containers") {
    const containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
    document.querySelectorAll('.container').forEach(container =>
      container.classList.add('hidden'));
    let uRandom = uniqueRandomFactory(100);
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
      containers[uRandom()].classList.remove('hidden');
    }
    return;
  }
  if (evt.target.id === "show-all") {
    document.querySelectorAll('.hidden').forEach(container =>
      container.classList.remove('hidden'));
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  position: fixed;
  top: -5000px;
}
```

```html
<button id="hide-containers">Hide random containers</button>
<button id="show-all">Show all containers</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advanced solution mate. In the mean time I have found a way how to get my code working fine but here I've learned some more stuff. Ty!